# Java selenium - pretty cucumber reports not generated with screenshot

Tags: java, cucumber

could you tell me how to generate pretty html reports with screenshot ? After I run the test the "cucumber-reports.html" does not exist. Only "image.png" file is generated.

```
  package cucumber.Options;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/features",
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/reports/cucumber-reports.html"},
        glue= {"stepDefs"},
        stepNotifications = true,
        monochrome = true
        )
public class TestRunner {
}
```

Method that does screenshot

```
@After
    public void afterTest(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {
        if (!scenario.isFailed()) {
           // String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//src" + "//Screenshots" + scenario + ".png";

            final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", scenario.getName());
            String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//target" + "//reports";
            File sourceFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, new File(directory, "image.png"));
        }

        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cucumber</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>picocontainer</groupId>
            <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.monochromata.cucumber/reporting-plugin -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.2</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate pretty HTML reports with screenshots in Cucumber, you can use the Cucumber HTML Reporter plugin. Here are the steps to implement it:

1 Add the dependency for the Cucumber HTML Reporter plugin to your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2 Modify your CucumberOptions annotation to include the plugin and set the plugin attribute to use the

```
com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter: prefix.
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {
        "pretty",
        "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"
    },
    ...
)
```

3 Create a new class called ExtentReportListener that extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests and implements the IReporter interface. This class will be responsible for generating the HTML report.

```
public class ExtentReportListener extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests implements IReporter {

    private ExtentReports extent;
    private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "target/";
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "cucumber-extent.html";

    @Override
    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
        init();
        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
            Map<String, ISuiteResult> result = suite.getResults();
            for (ISuiteResult r : result.values()) {
                ITestContext context = r.getTestContext();
                buildTestNodes(context.getPassedTests(), Status.PASS);
                buildTestNodes(context.getFailedTests(), Status.FAIL);
                buildTestNodes(context.getSkippedTests(), Status.SKIP);
            }
        }
        extent.flush();
    }

    private void init() {
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(OUTPUT_FOLDER + FILE_NAME);
        htmlReporter.config().setEncoding("utf-8");
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Automation Test Results");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Automation Test Results");
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);

        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.setReportUsesManualConfiguration(true);
    }

    private void buildTestNodes(IResultMap tests, Status status) {
        ExtentTest test;
        if (tests.size() > 0) {
            for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
                test = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
                for (String group : result.getMethod().getGroups())
                    test.assignCategory(group);
                if (result.getThrowable() != null) {
                    test.log(status, result.getThrowable());
                } else {
                    test.log(status, "Test " + status.toString().toLowerCase() + "ed");
                }
                if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
                    try {
                        test.fail("Screenshot",
                                MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(takeScreenshot()).build());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        test.fail("Screenshot not available");
                    }
                }
                extent.flush();
            }
        }
    }

    private String takeScreenshot() {
        String fileName = "screenshot.png";
        String directory = OUTPUT_FOLDER + "screenshots/";
        new File(directory).mkdirs();
        File sourceFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, new File(directory + fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            fileName = "screenshot-not-available.png";
        }
        return directory + fileName;
    }
}
```

4 In the ExtentReportListener class, you will also need to create a method to take a screenshot of the web page when a test fails. The method should return the path to the screenshot file.

5 Modify your step definitions to use the ExtentCucumberAdapter. To do this, add the following line to the top of your step definitions file:
@ExtendWith({ExtentCucumberAdapter.class})

6 Finally, run your tests with TestNG, and the HTML report with screenshots will be generated in the target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-extent.html file.

---

Another way to generate pretty HTML reports with screenshots in Cucumber, you can use the Cucumber Extent Reporter plugin. This plugin provides a comprehensive and customizable HTML report with detailed information on the test results along with the screenshots.

Here are the steps to add the Cucumber Extent Reporter plugin to your project:

1 Add the following dependency to your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2 Update the @CucumberOptions annotation in your TestRunner class as follows:

```
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/features",
        plugin = {"pretty", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"},
        glue= {"stepDefs"},
        stepNotifications = true,
        monochrome = true
        )
public class TestRunner {
}
```

3 Modify your @After method to include the following code:

```
@After
public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        try {
            byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", scenario.getName());
            extentTest.fail("Test Failed");
            extentTest.addScreenCaptureFromBase64String(new String(screenshot), scenario.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        extentTest.pass("Test Passed");
    }
    driver.quit();
}
```

4 Create an extent-config.xml file in your project and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extent>
    <configuration>
        <!-- report theme -->
        <theme>standard</theme>
        <!-- document encoding -->
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <!-- protocol for script and stylesheets -->
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <!-- title of the document -->
        <documentTitle>Cucumber Extent Report</documentTitle>
        <!-- report name - displayed at top-nav -->
        <reportName>Cucumber Extent Report</reportName>
        <!-- location of charts in the report -->
        <chartLocation>./</chartLocation>
        <!-- time zone for timestamps -->
        <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
    </configuration>
</extent>
```

5 Finally, run your test suite and the HTML report will be generated in the output folder.
Note: You may need to modify the code to suit your project's requirements.

---

Here's how to add the extentTest:

1 Declare a global `ExtentReports` and `ExtentTest` object in your

```
TestRunner class:
public class TestRunner {
    private static ExtentReports extentReports;
    private static ExtentTest extentTest;
    // ...
}
```

2 Initialize the `extentReports` object in the `@BeforeClass` method:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
    String reportPath = "./output/extent-report.html";
    ExtentSparkReporter sparkReporter = new ExtentSparkReporter(reportPath);
    sparkReporter.config().setReportName("Cucumber Extent Report");
    extentReports = new ExtentReports();
    extentReports.attachReporter(sparkReporter);
}
```

3 Create an instance of `ExtentTest` in the `@Before` method:
@Before
public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {
extentTest = extentReports.createTest(scenario.getName());
// ...
}

`ExtentTest` is a class provided by the ExtentReports library to create test logs in the report. In the provided code, `extentTest` is an instance of the `ExtentTest` class which is created in the `@Before` method of the `TestRunner` class. This instance is then used to log the status of the test and attach screenshots in the `@After` method.

The `ExtentTest` class has several methods to log information about the test such as `pass()`, `fail()`, `warning()`, `skip()`, etc. You can call these methods on the `extentTest` instance to log the test status. For example, in the provided code, `extentTest.pass("Test Passed")` is used to log the test passed status and `extentTest.fail("Test Failed")` is used to log the test failed status.

Additionally, you can also log other information about the test such as the test description, author, category, etc. using the `ExtentTest` class methods. For example, `extentTest.info("Test Description")` can be used to log the test description. You can refer to the ExtentReports documentation for more information on how to use the `ExtentTest` class to log information in the report.

I hope this helps you generate pretty HTML reports with screenshots in your Cucumber project.

Comment: second solution seems faster but where is class ExtentTest ?  extentTest.fail("Test Failed");
            extentTest.addScreenCaptureFromBase64String(new String(screenshot), scenario.getName());

Comment: can you show the code of ExtentTest class ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all we should take screenshot on the failure. For passed test cases its not required.

And use below code. Why are you coping the screenshot?

```
@After()
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario){
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", "Screenshot");
        }
}
```